# zerofree verbose returns what?

Tags: filesystems, ext4, ext3, ext2, sparse-files

`zerofree -v /dev/sda1` returned
`123642/1860888/3327744`.

The man page does not explain what those numbers are:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/zerofree.8.html

I found some code on github:
https://github.com/haggaie/zerofree/blob/master/zerofree.c

And there's this line:

```
if ( verbose ) {
  printf("\r%u/%u/%u\n", modified, free, fs->super->s_blocks_count);
}
```

So I guess the middle number was the free space (in kB?), the first one might be the amount that was written over with zeros, and the last one lost me.

What do you think?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have the same tool installed on Fedora 19, and I noticed in the `.spec` file a URL which lead to this page titled: [Keeping filesystem images sparse](http://intgat.tigress.co.uk/rmy/uml/index.html). This page included some examples for creating test data so I ran the commands to create the corresponding files.

#### Example

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=fs.image bs=1024 seek=2000000 count=0
$ /sbin/mke2fs fs.image

$ ls -l fs.image 
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 2048000000 Jan  4 21:42 fs.image

$ du -s fs.image 
32052   fs.image
```

When I ran the `zerofree -v` command I got the following:

```
$ zerofree -v fs.image 
...counting up percentages 0%-100%...
0/491394/500000
```

#### Interrogating with filefrag

When I used the tool `filefrag` to interrogate the `fs.image` file I got the following.

```
$ filefrag -v fs.image 
Filesystem type is: ef53
File size of fs.image is 2048000000 (500000 blocks of 4096 bytes)
 ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
   0:        0..     620:   11714560..  11715180:    621:            
   1:    32768..   32769:   11716608..  11716609:      2:   11715181:
   2:    32892..   33382:   11716732..  11717222:    491:   11716610:
   3:    65536..   66026:   11722752..  11723242:    491:   11717223:
...
```

The `s_block_count` referenced in your source code also coincided with the source code for my version of `zerofree.c`.

```
    if ( verbose ) {
            printf("\r%u/%u/%u\n", nonzero, free,
                            current_fs->super->s_blocks_count) ;
    }
```

So we now know that `s_blocks_count` is the 500,000 blocks of 4096 bytes.

#### Interrogating with tune2fs

We can also query the image file `fs.image` using `tune2fs`.

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l fs.image | grep -i "block"
Block count:              500000
Reserved block count:     25000
Free blocks:              491394
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      122
Blocks per group:         32768
Inode blocks per group:   489
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
```

From this output we can definitely see that the 2nd and 3rd numbers being reported by `zerofree` are in fact:

```
Free blocks:              491394
Block count:              500000
```

#### Back to the source code

The 1st number being reported is in fact the number of blocks that are found that are not zero. This can be confirmed by looking at the actual source code for `zerofree`.

There is a counter called, `nonzero` which is getting incremented in the main loop that's analyzing the free blocks.

```
            if ( i == current_fs->blocksize ) {
                    continue ;
            }

            ++nonzero ;

            if ( !dryrun ) {
                    ret = io_channel_write_blk(current_fs->io, blk, 1, empty) ;
                    if ( ret ) {
                            fprintf(stderr, "%s: error while writing block\n", argv[0]) ;
                            return 1 ;
                    }
            }
```

#### Conclusion

So after some detailed analysis it would look like those numbers are as follows:

- number of nonzero free blocks encountered (which were subsequently zeroed)
- number of free blocks within the filesystem
- total number of blocks within the filesystem

Comment: A small correction to the otherwise very detailed answer: The first number is the number of **free** non-zero blocks. (I.e. it does not count non-zero file blocks). As such, it is never larger than the number of free blocks. If you run zerofree (without -n) on a filesystem, then run it again (optionally with -n for dry-run) you will see that the first number has changed to 0, even with non-zero file data on the filesystem.